# Spring AMQP retry policy - wait with retrying until external system is reachable

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Our application is storing data the user enters in SalesForce. We are using Spring AMQP (RabbitMQ) to be able to store data and run the application even if SalesForce is not reachable (scheduled downtimes or else).

So once SalesForce is not available the queue should wait with retrying messages until it is up again. Is this possible using the CircuitBreakerRetryPolicy or do i have to implement a custom RetryPolicy?

Currently i just have a simply retry policy which should be replaced by a complex one that blocks the retries until the external system is reachable again.

```
@Bean
    RetryOperationsInterceptor salesForceInterceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
                .retryPolicy(simpleRetryPolicy())
                .build();
    }
```

Message listener:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        .....
    } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
        //TODO probablyy wrong exception
        throw new AmqpTimeoutException("Salesforce can not be accessed, retry later");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Fatal error with message to salesforce, do not retry", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code? Are you using RabbitTemplate?

Comment: Using queues, I can't understand what it's your problem. If the SalesForce is not available, the messages will be waiting to be consumed on the Queue. When the SalesForce be available, it will starts to consume the Queue. You can need a retry policy, per example, if you have some service consuming the Queue that also tries to connect with SalesForce (to send the message information to him), but the SalesForce is not available. In that case you can use a retry policy to continue to trying to connect before give up (discarding or sending the message to a DLQ, per example).

Comment: Yes, `CircuitBreakerRetryPolicy` is the way to go, but I agree with @Dherik that it's somehow unclear from the RabbitMQ queue perspective: if listener is not available, no any messages are going to be consumer from the queue

Comment: Yes there is a consumer, which is a rest client that tries to connect to SalesForce, now in a case of a network exception (external system is not reachable) i want the consumer to stop consuming messages and retry only when it is assured that the network failure is resolved.

Comment: @ArtemBilan could you give an example how to use the CircuitBreakerRetryPolicy in this case, i did not find any examples...